# ./node_modules/react-router-dom/node_modules/warning/warning.js Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, react-router-dom

I install `yarn add react-router-dom` and it shows error when import `"react-router-dom"`

Error message

```
./node_modules/react-router-dom/node_modules/warning/warning.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/krittiyaclark/Documents/my-portfolio-react/node_modules/react-router-dom/node_modules/warning/warning.js'
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-portfolio-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-changed": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-mdl": "^1.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Please help! I stuck for a long time.
Thank you!

Comment: Show your import. Here is example how it should be done https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/example-basic-routing

Comment: this link does not work any more

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't run `yarn install` yet, you need to run it to install all your dependencies. If you have installed them before, delete `.cache` directory from your project directory (`rm -rf .cache`) and run `yarn install` again.

Answer (score 3):

I just created an app with `create-react-app` and added `react-router-dom` as you did and everything is working fine, the only differences that I have are some package versions:

```
{
  "name": "quicktest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Try to run [npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update.html) to update them and restart your app.

Also, apparently, the release [4.3.1](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v4.3.1) of `react-router-dom` fixed something related to this error (What's odd is this is the version that you're using):
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Once I had this issue and I tried stopping all the Node processes in the process explorer. Also, try to install the package from a command line tool.

This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: restarting node solved the problem. it works for me as well. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue when I updated some npm packages in my react & laravel project, so all I did was to restart the react with the command npm start, the problem solved.